# MySQL: How to choose an appropriate SQLSTATE value for a signal?

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling, signals, mariadb

***This is a technical question with a subjectively correct answer, not one which asks for opinions! Please don't delete it for being "not constructive" before you read it. Thx!***

Hi!

I would like to raise SIGNALs when I detect certain errors in triggers and other functions I wrote, and then I would like to handle them within the outer function. There are multiple types of errors, which have to be handled differently. First, I thought I would be able to differentiate between the SIGNALs by checking the MESSAGE_TEXT inside the HANDLER which would catch all '45000's, but then I came to realize that accessing the MESSAGE_TEXT in the HANDLER is not possible (at least not under 10.1.21-MariaDB what I have to use). So now I want to raise SIGNALs with different SQLSTATE values for each error type to be able to make them apart.

**How should I choose the SQLSTATE values, corresponding to the individual errors?**

I understand that the first two characters specify the class; '00'=>success, '01'=>warning, '02'=>not found, > '02'=>exception. I also understand that '45000' means *unhandled user-defined exception* thus it is the value for a generic user raised SIGNAL. However, **am I free two choose any value to my signal's last three characters if it starts with a value greater than '02'?**

I mean, clearly not, since '42000' can, for example, mean ER_SP_WRONG_NAME (Incorrect routine name) which is an error raised by the server.

So what is the correct strategy? **How to choose a proper SQLSTATE for a user raised SIGNAL which will not collide with any SQLSTATE that already means something?**

Comment: I suggest you read through the MySQL and MariaDB documentation that lists all the existing `SQLSTATE` values. Then use something else.

Comment: @Barmar:
Well, yeah; First, have you seen that thing? There are literally thousands of them. Although, I could (theoretically)  regex them out from the manual and then check my choice against them. BUT, secondly, these are subject to change and multiplication. So, if I just chose one, than it could very well happen, that in an upcoming version my choice will collide with a predefined one. Which might result in my code braking in spectacular fashion.

Comment: I suspect there's not really any good solution. I found this in the [MariaDB manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sqlstate/): For user-defined conditions, MariaDB and MySQL recommend the '45000' SQLSTATE class.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you! The link was actually very informative. So I take it as; I should have my SQLSTATEs in the '45' class, and in that I am free to choose which ever subclass I like. Further more, the link also reads: _"The standard SQL specification says that classes beginning with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, A, B, C, D, E, F and G are reserved for standard-defined classes, while other classes are vendor-specific."_ So probably it is a good idea to avoid those in general. Although, it also says, that: _"However, MariaDB and MySQL do not strictly obey this rule."_ Soooo, I mean com'on kids...